# views/home.pug:13:1 Unexpected block links

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm working on a login/register project with pug,nodejs and express.
As I press my register button in my form I have the error :

> views/home.pug:13:1 Unexpected block links

Here is my home.pug file

```
extends layout

mixin message(opp, name)
    if(opp)
        h1.greeting Logged in as 
            span=name 
    else 
        h1.greeting Welcome 
            span=name 
            |  to our website


append links 
    li(style="float: right;")
        a(href="/loggout") Loggout 

block content
    .dashboard 
        .user 
            +message(opp, name)
```

My users are still registered in my database, but somehow I don't have my greeting message.

NOTE:
line 13 is `append links` and i'm passing

```
var pwd = body.password;
body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd,10); 
var bind = [ ]; 
for(prop in body){ 
    bind.push(body[prop]); 
} 
let sql = INSERT INTO users(username, fullname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?); 
pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, result) { 
    if(err) throw err; 
    callback(result.insertId);
```

Comment: which one is line 13?
Also what data are you passing?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan line 13 is "append links" and i'm passing         var pwd = body.password;
    
        body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd,10);

  
        var bind = [ ];
        for(prop in body){
            bind.push(body[prop]);
        }
        let sql = `INSERT INTO users(username, fullname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;

        pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(result.insertId);

Comment: the code looks incomplete some how, can you give me JSON of what data is being passed to render function?

Comment: Is there a `block links` defined in your `layout` file?

Comment: @sean there is a block content defined

Comment: @MM is it named `links` though?